# bootstrapping an ubuntu ec2 instance using chef and knife

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am bootstrapping a ec2 ubuntu based chef node using chef, it creates an instance but it says `Failed to authenticate ubuntu - trying password authand` 
asks for the password. But a newly created ubuntu ec2 instance will not have any kind of password set. Throws an error

```
  ERROR: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: ubuntu@ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XX.com
```

How do I bypass this event and also whats the problem, do I have to make any changes in the configurations.

Kindly help me I am new to the chef.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

As I know EC2 instances are using ssl certificate  authentication, it seems that you not assign key pair to created instances.

Comment: I was able to find the solution to I need to specify the path of my ssh key.